# Show points in a 3x3 box around points in an image array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array which represents an image, and from that image I've got another array (called points) which represents the positions of specific pixels of that image. What I want to do is make a new image array for which every pixel has the value zero other than a 3x3 box of pixels around the pixels specified in the points array.

So far to get another array which just has the single pixel specified I use:

```
new_im_array[points] = im_array[points]
```

Both image arrays are 500x500 and the points array is a 2xn where n is the number of pixels specified and the two list contained are x and y coordinates.

I've tried various things but I'm fairly new to python and I think it's getting more complicated than it should be considering how simple the operation should be.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It's not as simple as you'd think.  Can you use `scipy`?  `scipy.ndimage.binary_dilation` is made for this

Comment: I can use `scipy`, I'll have a look into the `binary_dilation` function, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scipy.ndimage.binary_dilation`:

```
from scipy.ndimage import binary_dilation

struct = np.ones((3,3)).astype(bool)
mask = np.zeros_like(im_array).astype(bool)
mask[points] = True
dilated_mask = binary_dilation(mask, structure = struct)
new_im_array = im_array * dilated_mask
```

You can make also do `struct[1, 1] = False` after it is created if you want just the pixels around your pixels, but not including them.

Comment: That has worked brilliantly, thanks for the help.